# nth-child doesn't work when the tag SPAN is on

Tags: css

Here is my code

```
<span></span>
<div class='box'>title</div>
<style>div.box:nth-child(1) { color: red; }</style>
```

It works when I delete the `span` tag or any other tag which is over the box, but not when I leave it as is. Why is it so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the div is now the second child. Use `:nth-of-type(n)` instead.

```
 <style>
  div.box:nth-of-type(1) { color: red; }
 </style>
```

That will select the first `div`

Comment: I've used :nth-of-type to my code but it doesn't work anyway. You can check it on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GtmmF/)

Comment: @user2679576. Look again at your fiddle. You did not use `nth-of-type`. If you change it, you will see that `nth-of-type` works on your fiddle.

Comment: You are applying `nth-of-type` to the wrong element. Use this: `.gallery-item:nth-of-type(4) .wp-caption-text`

Answer (score 5):

Use `:nth-of-type` .

Basically `:nth-child` counts ALL the siblings. Regardless of type of element. However :`nth-of-type` takes into account the element selected.